# How to use Multiple Interrupt in STM32?

Tags: stm32, interrupt, hal

I am using interrupt events in stm32f100 series. My question is soft to understand. There is a mutual function to control EXTI10 to EXTI15.

```
void EXTI15_10_IRQHandler(void)
{
    if(__HAL_GPIO_EXTI_GET_IT(GPIO_PIN_10) != RESET){
      
   //functionevent
    __HAL_GPIO_EXTI_CLEAR_IT(GPIO_PIN_10);
    HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_PIN_10);
    }
    
    //EXTI11 
    if(__HAL_GPIO_EXTI_GET_IT(GPIO_PIN_11) != RESET){
      
    //function event
    __HAL_GPIO_EXTI_CLEAR_IT(GPIO_PIN_11);
    HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_PIN_11);
    }

}
```

How can ı manage EXTI10 and EXTI12 events when they ınterrupt seperately. When they ıntterrupt

Comment: I am sorry for this. I editted it. Could you check again?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to test the EXTI registers to see which one(s) have triggered an interrupt.

Something like:

```c
void EXTI10_15_IRQHandler(void)
{
  if (LL_EXTI_IsActiveFallingFlag_0_31(LL_EXTI_LINE_10) != RESET)
  {
    LL_EXTI_ClearFallingFlag_0_31(LL_EXTI_LINE_10);
    
    // Process EXTI10 interrupt
  }

  if (LL_EXTI_IsActiveFallingFlag_0_31(LL_EXTI_LINE_12) != RESET)
  {
    LL_EXTI_ClearFallingFlag_0_31(LL_EXTI_LINE_12);
    
    // Process EXTI12 interrupt
  }
}
```

This is an example where the interrupts were configured for a falling edge. You may need to adjust if you use some other interrupt configuration.

This example is where the project is configured to use the "low-level" `LL` driver interface. There is probably something similar using the HAL, or you could do direct register accesses. (Look at the `LL` driver to see what registers it uses.)

Comment: Sir, can you warn me, if there is sth wrong on my code.

Comment: If you are clearing the interrupt yourself, there is no need to call into the HAL. Just call your own function to handle that interrupt. If you do want to go through the HAL, then don't clear the interrupt in the ISR, just call the HAL. It will clear the interrupt. You'll then need to implement `HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback()` to handle the interrupt. If it was me I'd just bypass the HAL and do it myself.

Comment: I editted the weird apperance of the function. Do you mean that there is no need to use __HAL_GPIO_EXTI_CLEAR_IT(GPIO_PIN_10); functions. But other things are true right?

Comment: I think that if you are going to call the HAL (and therefore also provide a `HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback()` function) then you don't probably don't need to use `__HAL_GPIO_EXTI_CLEAR_IT()`. But if you choose to not call the HAL and just call your own interrupt handler, you would need to clear the interrupt. Can't say for sure since I'm not trying it, but that is my belief.

Answer (score 0):

`void EXTI15_10_IRQHandler(void)` will be called upon EXTI interrupt on any line among EXTI10 - EXTI15 (read GPIO pin 10 through GPIO pin 15). You have to determine the source in the handler itself. The structure of your handler should generally resemble something like this:

```
void EXTI15_10_IRQHandler(void){

  uint8_t sourcepin = get_exti10_15_source_pin(); //tests EXTI registers, returns pin number

  switch(sourcepin){
    case(10):
      gpio_10_exti_handler();
      break;
    case(15):
      gpio_15_exti_handler();
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }

}
```

Comment: Could you look at my edit on the description. Is it wrong usage for this event?

Comment: It's pretty much exactly my code or the code from the other answer by pcmacfarlane, they're all the same thing in terms of actual logic. Your code seems correct now. If all functions work as expected, your latest iteration of code should work.